# VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, remix

Here my contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./CertificateOwnable.sol";
import "./CertificateStorage.sol";

contract Certificate is CertificateOwnable {

    CertificateStorage certificateStorage;

    constructor(address _certificateAddress) public {
        certificateStorage = CertificateStorage(_certificateAddress);
    }

    function addCertificateTotal(string memory _universityName, 
                        string memory _typeOfDegree, 
                        string memory _major, 
                        string memory _name, 
                        uint256 _dateOfBirth) public onlyOwner returns(address) {

        address certificateNo = certificateStorage.setCertificateTotal(_universityName, 
                                                            _typeOfDegree, 
                                                            _major, 
                                                            _name, 
                                                            _dateOfBirth);

        return (certificateNo);
    }
}
```

My CertificateOwnable

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract CertificateOwnable {

    address public ownerAddress;

    event OwnershipRenounced(address indexed previousOwner);
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() public {
        ownerAddress = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == ownerAddress);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        emit OwnershipTransferred(ownerAddress, newOwner);
        ownerAddress = newOwner;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipRenounced(ownerAddress);
        ownerAddress = address(0);
    }
}
```

My CertificateStorage

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./CertificateStorageOwnable.sol";

contract CertificateStorage is CertificateStorageOwnable {

    address public certificateAddress;

    event AuthorizedCaller(address caller);
    event DeAuthorizedCaller(address caller);

    function authorizeCaller(address _caller) public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
        authorizedCaller[_caller] = 1;
        emit AuthorizedCaller(_caller);
        return true;
    }

    constructor() public {
        authorizedCaller[msg.sender] = 1;
        emit AuthorizedCaller(msg.sender);
    }

    modifier onlyAuthCaller(){
        certificateAddress = msg.sender;
        require(authorizedCaller[msg.sender] == 1);
        _;
    }
    struct certificate_total {
        string universityName;
        string typeOfDegree;
        string major;
        string name;
        uint256 dateOfBirth;
    }
    mapping(address => certificate_total) certificateTotalMapping;

    certificate_total certificateTotal;

    function setCertificateTotal(string memory _universityName, 
                        string memory _typeOfDegree, 
                        string memory _major, 
                        string memory _name, 
                        uint256 _dateOfBirth) public onlyAuthCaller returns(address) {

        uint tmpData = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, now)));
        address certificateNo = address(tmpData);

        certificateTotal.universityName = _universityName;
        certificateTotal.typeOfDegree = _typeOfDegree;
        certificateTotal.major = _major;
        certificateTotal.name = _name;
        certificateTotal.dateOfBirth = _dateOfBirth;

        certificateTotalMapping[certificateNo]= certificateTotal;

        return certificateNo;
    }
}
```

CertificateStorageOwnable is like a CertificateOwnable

**Please help me,
I am learning how to write a smart contract.
When I debug on REMIX, there is an error like in the picture**

```
transact to Certificate.addCertificateTotal errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the 
transaction to get more information.
```

Comment: Most likely some of the `require` statements reverts the transaction. One option is to just comment out the `require` statements one by one and see which one causes the revert and then figure out what's wrong with your input.

Answer (score 0):

The error is when you call `setCertificateTotal` and happens with the modifier `onlyAuthCaller`.

You probably didn't set up beforehand the calling contract as authorized by calling `authorizeCaller(address _caller)`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have an authorization when deploy contract. But it still doesn't work

Comment: You have authorization for **you**, for the address you control. When you call the `addCertificateTotal` function, it calls the `setCertificateTotal` function, and in there, `msg.sender` is not your address but the address of the contract that called it.